# Angular push is not pushing but replacing data in list

Tags: angular, typescript, angular7

I have some data loaded into my view using `*ngFor`.

When the page loads it currently adds some data into the view in the list.

In the view I have this:

In the app.component.html

```
<button (click)="addToList()"></button>


<ul *ngFor="let list of datalist">
  <li>{{ list.title }}</a></li>
</ul>
```

In the app.component.ts

```
datalist = [];

ngOnInit() {
  // Loads data....
  this.datalist = myLoadedData; // So when the page is loaded some data is loaded into datalist and shown in view

}

addToList() {

  this.datalist.push(
    {
        title: 'Item 2'

      }
  );

}
```

My problem is that when I click the button to push some new data into the list it's not pushing the new data into it, it's actually replacing the current data.

How can I fix this?

Comment: I created a StackBlitz with your code and I don't see any problem: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dggjvo Are you sure you're not doing something else when clicking the button?

Comment: May be unrelated, but you are also closing a <a> tag, but never opening it 
`<li>{{ list.title }}</a></li>`

Comment: How do the data look from `datalist`?

Comment: I've added a console.log to the end of addToList method and it's actually pushing the new data. It's just the view that's only giving me 1 item. Could it have something to do with the component being created at runtime?

Comment: @PaulC Could you share a StackBlitz with your code so we can examine it more precisely?

Comment: I can see that for some reason it's replacing the whole <ul></ul> which a new one and not the <li></li> as it should

Comment: That's because your `*ngFor` is on the `<ul>` tag instead of the `<li>` tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the problem is not with the pushing but with your binding.

try this:

```
addToList() {
this.datalist.push(
{
    title: 'Item 2'

  }
);
  this.datalist=[...this.datalist];
}
```

and by the way it seems like you close an `</a>` tag without opening it.

Answer (score 0):

Not Sure if you are using onPush change detection strategy, if so your component will not detect any changes upon mutating the data. Can you try

```
this.datalist = this.datalist.concat(
    {
        title: 'Item 2'

      }
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a track-by function to ensure your items are correctly calculated :

```html
*ngFor="let list of datalist; trackBy: customTB"
```

```
customTB(index, item) {
  return `${index}-${item.id}`; // Add an ID to your items
}
```